# How to disable media_automount_open in Ubuntu through a script

Tags: python, ubuntu, admin, dbus

I writing a script that mounts and unmounts several USB devices quickly. When a new device is mounted, Ubuntu, by default, opens up a file browser window for that device. That behavior gets very annoying when it is mounting multiple devices. 
I looked online, and found a tutorial explaining how to disable that feature through the gui (http://www.liberiangeek.net/2010/09/disableenable-auto-mount-ubuntu-10-0410-10-maverick-meerkat/) , but I wish to find a way to do that from within the script.

This is how I am currently mounting the devices:

```
 def mount_all(self):
        paths = self._get_partitions()
        vfat_path = paths[0][0]
        vfat = self.sysbus.get_object(SD.udisks_bus, vfat_path) 
        vfat_props = dbus.Interface(vfat, dbus_interface=SD.prop_bus)
        if vfat_props.Get(vfat_path, 'DeviceIsMounted'):
           self.fat = vfat_props.Get(vfat_path, 'DeviceMountPaths')[0]
        else:
           while True:
               try:
                   self.fat = vfat.FilesystemMount('vfat', {}, dbus_interface=SD.device_bus)
                   break
               except dbus.exceptions.DBusException:
                   time.sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be way simpler than I had thought. You can edit the .gconf properties with the tool `gconftool-2` as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17249/how-do-i-use-the-gconf-editor)